# Prevent Copying text box in form

Tags: powershell

I have created a form with two Text Boxes and I want to prevent the technician from being able to Copy the text from the first box and pasting it into the second box. I haven't been able to locate anything.

Comment: Do you want them to be able to type in both boxes?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I want them to type in both boxes.
The first box would be something like 123456 and then they click a Checkbox which removes the first box and enables a second box for them to validate the entry. If they can Copy from first box and Paste into second box, it defeats the purpose of the validation box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkbox idea won;t stop them from copy pasting into BOTH boxes from a text document or similar. But you could try something like this:

```
$TextBox1.ShortcutsEnabled = $false
$TextBox2.ShortcutsEnabled = $false
```